# Get all matches in a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have this URL:

```
uploads/offers/picture/_YToxOntzOjc6Im9wdGlvbnMiO3M6MTY6Inpvb21Dcm9wLDI4MS_/_wyMDAiO30=_/518edc82d94b0-201341717250_descuen_a06d000000fkvwpiak_1_1.jpg
```

And I need to get all `/_(.*)_/` parts, but my `preg_match_all` expression seems bad formed:

```
preg_match_all('#/_([^_/]+)_/#', $url, $params);
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /_YToxOntzOjc6Im9wdGlvbnMiO3M6MTY6Inpvb21Dcm9wLDI4MS_/
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => YToxOntzOjc6Im9wdGlvbnMiO3M6MTY6Inpvb21Dcm9wLDI4MS
        )
)
```

And I need

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /_YToxOntzOjc6Im9wdGlvbnMiO3M6MTY6Inpvb21Dcm9wLDI4MS_/
            [1] => /_wyMDAiO30=_/
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => YToxOntzOjc6Im9wdGlvbnMiO3M6MTY6Inpvb21Dcm9wLDI4MS
            [1] => wyMDAiO30=
        )
)
```

Some problem with common string parts in expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with your current solution is that it matches the `/` at the end of the expression as [Explosion Pill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16550378/50079) says; using positive lookahead will solve that problem.

Another possible issue is that the `[^_/]` part may end up breaking the regex if the input contains underscores as part of the matches you do want to capture.

To solve both issues at once:

```
~/_(.+?)_(?=/)~
```

This seems to me to be closer to what you are after: "whenever you see the sequence `/_` start capturing all input until you come across the sequence `_/`". Lone underscores inside the input will not break this.

Answer (score 2):

The final `/` in the regex ends up consuming it.  One simple way to get around this is to use a lookahead.

```
preg_match_all('#/_([^_/]+)_(?=/)#', $url, $params);
```

Comment: lookahead that big unknown.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `/` in between doesn't match twice, however, you could use lookahead/behind assertions:

```
preg_match_all('#(?<=/_)[^_/]+(?=_/)#', $url,$params);

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(50) "YToxOntzOjc6Im9wdGlvbnMiO3M6MTY6Inpvb21Dcm9wLDI4MS"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "wyMDAiO30="
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression picks up TWO `_`, so the `wyMDAiO30=` part is skipped.

I suggest you use `explode("_", $url)` (or `preg_split(...)` if the above is just an example and you need regexes to recognize splitting characters/substrings).

If you really insist on using `preg_match_all`, check the documentation. There is a way to say "match this, but don't include it in the string". I think it's something like `#_([^_/]+)(?=_)#`.

Comment: The problem is with the `/`, not the `_`

Comment: Sorry, buy I can't explode by _ because the URL can have some _ no needed, the expression must be exactly /_.*_/

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would probably be to split the string first and then check for underscores:

```
<?php

$data = explode('/', $url);

foreach($data as $val) {
    if(substr($val, 0, 1) === '_' && substr($val, -1) === '_') {
        // ok
    }
}
```